# Apache Solr Java GC taking more than 1 hour in last 12 hour logs

Tags: java, java-8, solr, garbage-collection

I am running Solr on 6 Nodes (8 CPU, 32 GB RAM) each with the following configuration and GC is running too frequently and for long. Kindly suggest improvements:

Solr Java config:

```
 -DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks
    -DSTOP.PORT=7983
    -Dhost=10.0.140.240
    -Djetty.home=/opt/solr/server
    -Djetty.port=8983
    -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
    -Dnewrelic.environment=production-v2
    -Dsolr.data.home=
    -Dsolr.default.confdir=/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf
    -Dsolr.documentCache.initialSize=8339
    -Dsolr.documentCache.size=8339
    -Dsolr.filterCache.initialSize=8339
    -Dsolr.filterCache.size=8339
    -Dsolr.install.dir=/opt/solr
    -Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.excludes=
    -Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.includes=
    -Dsolr.log.dir=/var/solr/data/logs
    -Dsolr.log.muteconsole
    -Dsolr.queryResultCache.initialSize=6671
    -Dsolr.queryResultCache.size=6671
    -Dsolr.solr.home=/var/solr/data/data
    -Duser.timezone=UTC
    -DzkClientTimeout=30000
    -DzkHost=ip-10-0-12-249.ap-south-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-10-0-12-250.ap-south-1.compute.internal:2181,ip-10-0-12-251.ap-south-1.compute.internal:2181/solr
    -XX:+AggressiveOpts
    -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
    -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
    -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
    -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
    -XX:+PrintGCDetails
    -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
    -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
    -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
    -XX:+UseG1GC
    -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
    -XX:+UseLargePages
    -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
    -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
    -XX:ConcGCThreads=4
    -XX:G1ReservePercent=10
    -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M
    -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=80
    -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100
    -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8
    -XX:NewRatio=3
    -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=9
    -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/opt/solr/bin/oom_solr.sh 8983 /var/solr/data/logs
    -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
    -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m
    -XX:SurvivorRatio=4
    -Xloggc:/var/solr/data/logs/solr_gc.log
    -Xms23862m
    -Xmx23862m
    -Xss256k
    -javaagent:/opt/solr/contrib/newrelic/newrelic.jar
    -verbose:gc
```

GCeasy.io log analyser:

https://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMjMvMDQvMi9zb2xyX2djLmxvZy4wLS04LTMxLTMy&channel=WEB

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion it is _"running too frequently and for long"_? Maybe it is appropriate for your workload.

Comment: In the report it shows, it ran for 1 hr cummulatively in the last 12 hour log. Also it ran over 5,800 times. Isn't it too frequent? It runs for over 8 seconds on average. It's all there in gceasy report.

Comment: I think Mark's question was: what's your issue? Response time of Solr? Indexation duration?

Comment: Yea ... the fact that the GC is running 8% of the time is not an issue *per se*.  Neither is the fact that GC runs are 8 seconds on average.

Comment: Anyway, if your goal is to reduce the GC overheads, then you should switch to the Throughput collector.  G1GC is a low-pause collector, and low pause collectors have additional overheads compared to a "stop the world" collector.

Comment: Yes, our actual issue was Solr facet time..  we calculate min() and max() in facets which takes time..

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, optimizing GC times / overheads are unlikely to make much difference.  If the GC is currently running approximately 12th of the time, then even if you could reduce the GC cost to zero (which is impossible!) you only would increase the available CPU for non-GC work by ... ~8%. And 8% is an upper bound.  You would be lucky to get a 4% increase in available time, IMO.  My advice: look for ways to optimize the facet indexing, etc, directly.